# How can I call the same ViewController from two TabBar items?

Tags: iphone, sdk, tabbar

How can I call the same ViewController from two TabBar items?

I used:

> MyViewController *vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
>   MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
>
> UITabBarController *tabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
>   [tabs setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil] animated:NO];

But variables will be reset, I want to keep the variables.

My view controller contains TableView with listdata, I just want to show first three of them when I click one 2nd TabBar, but listdata variable is reset and become nil.

Any fix?
Thanks

Comment: So you want to show the same thing in two tabs? Why have two separate tabs then?

Comment: Because one is for showing all data in tableView, and other one is for showing specific data in tableView (e.g. Favorite items)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd do this, but this probably works.

```
MyViewController *vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; 

UITabBarController *tabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabs setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc1, nil] animated:NO];
```

Comment: It didn't work that way, it's showing two tabs, but only one is working, the second one is inactive.

Comment: My guess is that the UITabBarController class doesn't support that, I recommend you find another way to achieve what you are trying to do, maybe a singleton that populates the tables on both view controllers, or something like that. Besides, even if you manage for it to work like this, Apple might reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one of the view controllers be a subclass of another, and the subclass would have some data filtered out. UITabBarController has a delegate method that it calls when switching between tabs - you can use that to populate the lists as needed.